# Restore files after a reformat

Tags: windows, data-recovery

A couple of friends of mine had problems with their computer (OS crash) and let a friend fix it.

The problem is that he did a reformat and a fresh install of the OS without asking. They had all their videos (recorded by them) and all images stored on it and no backups.

The friend tried to restore the files with two different undelete applications without success. Are there any other ways to restore the files except taking the computer to a company specialized in data recovering?

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/128786/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows, and/or http://superuser.com/questions/6810/best-undelete-tool-for-ntfs-fat also [This](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery?sort=active&pagesize=15)

Comment: If you can't recover them yourself using the tools at hand, then you are pretty much resigned to taking it to a professional.

Comment: @techie007: correct me if I'm wrong: But doesn't a format make things harder than just a simple delete? i.e. do really a regular undelete application work in this case?

Comment: The tools offered in those questions cover partition recovery as well as undeletes. It's due to people using the terms interchangeably, and the fact that many of the tools do both jobs. Personally I recommend GetDataBack (see the linked questions/answers)

Comment: @techie007: add them as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) with **deep scan**, and don't write any new data to hard disk.(as it might overright the deleted file and make them Unrecoverable)